# Como crear un JDBC pool connection en glassfish?

Tags: mysql, java-ee, glassfish, jdbc

Un saludo a todos, estoy intentando crear un jdbc pool connection mysql desde glassfish , pero a la hora de crearlo me manda el siguiente error

[image: configuración]

[image: Error]

No se que hacer para solucionarlo, espero me ayuden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Últimamente he tenido problemas con GF al utilizar la consola de administración para crear recursos pero, la consola sigue funcionando y en últimas termina siendo muchísimo más rápido configurar el connection pool de ésta forma.

Teniendo en cuenta que glassfish haga parte de las variables de entorno `path`, en mi caso era agregar: *C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\bin;* a esa variable para poder utilizar `asadmin` desde cualquier parte.

Se abre la consola de comandos, y con el comando:

```
asadmin add-resources [ruta/a/proyect/xxx/glassfish-resources.xml]
```

Éste comando de inmediato nos crea tanto el `connection pool` como el `datasource`.